# Функция random и деление

Tags: python, случайные-числа

Как сделать, чтобы функция рандом выводила случайные числа, при делении которых получалось бы число без остатка?
Например:

```
from random import randint
x=randint(100, 999)
y=randint(2, 9)
z=x//y
```

Переменная z должна быть целым числом, получается, переменная y должна зависеть от переменной x, чтобы число получилось целым.

Comment: при целочисленном делении // в любом случае получится целое число

Comment: Требования к распределению есть? Если требуется равновероятное, то чуть сложнее. Если абы какое, то проще.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если требования к распределению строгие (равномерное распределение) и общее количество пар не велико (*1645* в нашем случае), то проще всего создать список всех возможных пар и выбирать из него:

```
import random


def random_pair(x_first, x_last, y_first, y_last):
    y_first = 2
    y_last = 9
    x_first = 100
    x_last = 999
    pairs = []
    for y in range(y_first, y_last + 1):
        # x_start = x_first округлённый вверх до числа кратного y
        x_start = y * ((x_first + y - 1) // y)
        for x in range(x_start, x_last + 1, y):
            pairs.append((x, y))
    return lambda: random.choice(pairs)


rp = random_pair(2, 9, 100, 999)
for _ in range(10):
    x, y = rp()
    print(f'{x}/{y}', end=' ')
print()
```

> ```
> $ python random-pairs.py
> 852/4 561/3 324/9 837/9 768/2 507/3 999/3 621/3 114/3 138/2
> ```

Answer (score 6):

Чтобы делилось без остатка, можно развернуть проблему - генерировать случайные сомножители `z` и `y`, и получать их произведение `x=z*y`, отбрасывая пары, дающие результаты вне нужного диапазона.

Answer (score 3):

```
from random import randint, choice

x = randint(100, 999)
# y = randint(2, 9)         # заменим за следующие команды

divisors = [el for el in range(2, 9+1) if x % el == 0]
y = choice(divisors)
```

---

*Объяснение:*

После сгенерирования первого числа нам нужно сгенерировать второе, но не из полного диапазона целых чисел от 2 до 9, но только из тех, которые являются делителями первого сгенерированного числа.

Для этого сначала

- создаем список `divisors` всех элементов `el` из диапазона от 2 до 9, которыми число `x` делится без остатка (т. е. с остатком `0`):   `x % el == 0`,
- затем применим

  - *не* функцию `randint()`, которая выбирает из полного диапазона, а
  - функцию `choice()`, которая выбирает случайный элемент из *списка*.

Comment: Стоит пояснить, что делать с простым числами и теми, что не имеют делителей в указанном диапазоне

Comment: @MBo, вы прав, но я не хотел заниматься побочными деталями типа `if not divisors:`, потому что не знаю, что в таком случае хочет автор сделать.